# Display disabled radio button

Tags: jhtml

I need to display a disabled radio button using JHTML but I can't find anything useful or any example I could use to learn. Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Checkout radiolist option of JHTML

```
JHTML::_('select.radiolist', $options, 'some label' );
```

Ref: https://docs.joomla.org/API16:JHtmlSelect/radiolist